# Activity lifecycle and class properties

Tags: android, android-activity

Any activity can be killed under certain circumstances (e.g. "Other applications need memory"). After this, `onCreate` is called again on the activity.

The documentation says that in this case the "process is killed". Does this mean that the whole Activity instance is gc'ed and constructed again or only the GUI parts?

Given:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private SomeClass someProperty = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        if (someProperty == null) someProperty = new SomeClass ();
        Log.d ("X", someProperty.toString () );
    }
}
```

**Will `someProperty` be `null` after the activity is killed and comes again to front, or will `someProperty` still be the same?**

I am asking this, as it is hard to emulate the condition "Other applications need memory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do nothing in `onSaveInstanceState()` method, **it will be null**. You might find some infomation useful reading this [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) about activity lifecycle.

If you want the `someProperty` to be saved when the Activity is not destroyed normally(i.e., the user press the BACK button or the app calls finish() ), you can override the `onSavedInstanceState()` method and save whatever you want. There is a more explicit example in the tutorial linked above.

Also, there is another [article](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle) and yet another [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html) that explain the lifecycle of activity quite clear.

Hope helpful.

**EDIT:**
About when the `onSavedInstanceState()` will not be called(i.e. "destroy normally", which might be a confusing expression), this article says and I quote:

> If the user interacts with an activity and presses the Back button or if the finish() method of an activity is called, the activity is removed from the current activity stack and recycled. In this case there is no instance state to save and the onSaveInstanceState() method is not called.
>
> If the user interacts with an activity and presses the Home button, the activity instance state must be saved. The onSaveInstanceState() method is called. If the user restarts the application it will resume or restart the last running activity. If it restarts the activity it provides the bundle with the save data to the onRestoreInstanceState() and onCreate() methods.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected I had to go through the saved instance state. What do you mean by "not destroyed normally"? Do you mean that `onSaveInstanceState` won't be called when the activity is destroyed, because the system decides to free up memory?

Comment: Sorry about the confusing expression. In fact, it is exactly the opposite. See my edit for detail.

Comment: Thank you a load for you amplification. Do you know what happens in the case of the activity is recycled because another process jumps to the front (e.g. a phone call) and due to memory lack the first activity is recycled. In this scenario is `onSaveInstanceState` called or not?

Comment: It is hard to emulate this scenario, so I am not completely sure about this. Yet based on the develop guide and api reference, I would say that we should and we can only treat this scenario as `onSaveInstanceState` would be called. (ps. In fact, this is not likely to happen as android maintains the process queue with a LRU list. So it is less likely to kill the recent used process unless under quite extreme situation.  Try [this](developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes) for more info about process recycle)